# React Native Android transition without animaiton

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

How do I transition between scenes without animations using Navigator?

When I do a Navigator.replace(), the view just switches instantly, I'd like to replicate this behavior with a Navigator.push() call.

I've been playing around with SceneConfigs and feel like that might be the right solution, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hacky solution here. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1953

var NoTransition = {
  opacity: {
    from: 1,
    to: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 1,
    type: 'linear',
    extrapolate: false,
    round: 100,
  },
};

```
return  {
            ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft,
            gestures: null,
            defaultTransitionVelocity: 100,
            animationInterpolators: {
              into: buildStyleInterpolator(NoTransition),
              out: buildStyleInterpolator(NoTransition),
            },
        };
```